# Perl DBI Error Msg: Can't call method "selectcol_arrayref" on an undefined value

Tags: perl, oracle, dbi

```
my $dblinks = '';
$dblinks = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref("select db_link from db_links where ticket=\'LOW\'");
my $success = 0;
for my $dblink (@$dblinks) {
  $success = eval {
    my ($ret) = $dbh->selectrow_array("select 1 from "
      . $dbh->quote_identifier($dblink, 'SYSIBM', "SYSDUMMY1") );
    $ret;
  };

  if ($success) {
    &Logging (3, $I, "connect_${G_CONNECT_COUNT}", "Connect success for $dblink");
  } else {
    # Read thru the selectcol_array, check for an oracle error
    $l_msg="$dblink Result doesn't match 1";
    @l_errstr=();
    &ConnectFailed ($p_host, $p_db, $p_ars, $p_ars_sev, $l_msg, $p_cid, @l_errstr);
    # Raise a Ticket with Oracle message
    &Logging (3, $I, "connect_${G_CONNECT_COUNT}", "Connect failed for $dblink");

  }
    $l_dbh->commit();
    $l_dbh->do(qq{alter session close database link  "$dblink"});

}
```

Comment: $l_dbh = DBI->connect($l_cstr, $G_CONF{TEST_USER}, $G_CONF{TEST_PASS}, { PrintError=>0, RaiseError=>0, AutoCommit=>1 });

                if ($l_dbh) {

Comment: sorry I deleted my previous comment without seeing yours.  See Sinan's answer.

Comment: See update to my answer: You assign the return from `connect` to `$l_dbh` but you try to invoke a method on `$dbh`.

Answer (score 5):

#### Update:

Simple, really, you assign the handle returned by the `connect` call to `$l_dbh` but invoke a method on `$dbh`. You **must** use [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html).

#### Original answer:

The database handle `$dbh` is not defined which means the connection failed. You should either check return values of your calls, or specify `{ RaiseError => 1}` in the `connect` call to find out the reason.

Further, there is no reason to prefix every sub invocation with `&`: Use `ConnectFailed( )` instead of `&ConnectFailed( )`, unless you know the effect of prefixing a sub invocation with `&` and desire to have that effect.

From [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html):

> A subroutine may be called using an explicit `&` prefix. The `&`  is optional in modern Perl, as are parentheses if the subroutine has been predeclared. The `&`  is not optional when just naming the subroutine, such as when it's used as an argument to `defined()` or `undef()`. Nor is it optional when you want to do an indirect subroutine call with a subroutine name or reference using the `&$subref()`  or `&{$subref}()`  constructs, although the `$subref->()` notation solves that problem.
>
> ... If a subroutine is called using the `&`  form, the argument list is optional, and if omitted, no `@_`  array is set up for the subroutine: the `@_` array at the time of the call is visible to subroutine instead. **This is an efficiency mechanism that new users may wish to avoid.** (emphasis added).

Answer (score 4):

You don't show where `$dbh` is assigned. Presumably you do so earlier. If you do not, then I beseech you to add these two litle lines to all your code files:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

...and they will save you from a world of hurt.

Earlier on when you create the db handle, you should check if something bad happened:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $username, $password)
        or die $DBI::errstr;
```

There is no real point in continuing with your program if you cannot get a db handle, is there? If you don't die, you should at least return from this function/method/area of code that is responsible for handling the DB.

There other issues with your code, such as using `eval {}` blocks everywhere and calling functions with `&`, but this has been covered quite amply in earlier questions on this site so I would encourage you to do a search.

Answer (score 0):

> my ($ret) =
>   $dbh->selectrow_array(**"select 1 from
>   "** 
>         . $dbh->quote_identifier($dblink,
>   **'SYSIBM'**, **"SYSDUMMY1"**) );

Im not an expert at DBI, but this here looks a little wierd to me. Why the single quotes around SYSIBM and double quotes around SYSDUMMY1? This probably wouldn't solve your problem, but it's a good practice. It's not manditory to Use Strict. That's a suggestion.

> $dblinks =
>   $dbh->selectcol_arrayref("select
>   db_link from db_links where
>   ticket=**\'LOW\'**");

This here other thing  that looks really odd is the escape Slashes. I would rewrite that too. It might not work, but it sure looks good.

> $sql = qq{**select db_link from** db_links
>   where ticket=LOW};
>
> $dblinks =
>   $dbh->selectcol_arrayref($sql, undef);