# How to get the exact Oracle Error message on a select without the text and store in variable

Tags: perl, oracle, error-handling, dbi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Perl DBI Error Msg: Can't call method “selectcol_arrayref” on an undefined value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388058/perl-dbi-error-msg-cant-call-method-selectcol-arrayref-on-an-undefined-value)

```
my ($ret) = $l_dbh->selectrow_array("select dummy from "
                        . $l_dbh->quote_identifier($dblink, 'SYSIBM', "SYSDUMMY1") );
                          $ret;
                           };
```

Comment: What is an error message without the text?  Do you mean the error code?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is hardly clear, but it sounds like you're looking for the [DBI error attributes](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#METHODS_COMMON_TO_ALL_HANDLES): `err` (the native database error code), `errstr` (the native database error message), and `state` (a standard SQLSTATE five character format, but not widely supported).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to follow your statement with:

```
my $sqlerr = $l_dbh->errstr;
```

However, you may not get that far if $l_dbh->{RaiseError} is set, as that will cause your program to crash on any error (with the error message).  So you will want to do a

```
$l_dbh->{RaiseError} = 0;
```

first